# Unix group-based access control with SVN over Apache

Tags: svn, apache2, access-control-list, user-management, groups

I have an SVN repository hosted over HTTPS wiht Apache 2. In an attempt to unify access control lists for SVN as well as other services on the server, and prevent having to deal with multiple copies of users and groups, I decided to have users authenticate using PAM with their unix users, and access control would therefore have to be based on the groups they belong to

I am able to control access to the SVN repository as a whole based on the following Apache config

```
DefineExternalAuth checkPassword pipe /usr/sbin/pwauth  
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Repo"
    AuthBasicProvider external
    AuthExternal checkPassword
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/svn/authz
    Order deny,allow
    Require unix-group svngroup
</Location>
```

And then in an attempt to fine-tune the access control lists for the repository itself, I set up the following authz

```
[therepo:/]
@svngroup = rw

[therepo:/restricted_files]
@svngroup = 
@vipgroup = rw
```

However, this fails, and the entire repository becomes restricted to all users no matter what group they're in. I get the following sort of errors in the log

```
Failed to load the mod_authz_svn config: Error while parsing config file: '/var/svn/authz': Access entry refers to undefined group '@svngroup'
```

Which tells me that it's not recognizing that svngroup is a valid unix group. Is there any solution to this? Or am I forced to have multiple copies of the users and group definitions?